# Escaping in-app Safari in social apps on iOS

Tags: javascript, mobile, safari, in-app

I'm currently working on a web-app which uses WebRTC and Google Sign Up. When accessed via LinkedIn, Reddit or any other app that opens the website in-app both of those features are not woking. So far, only Telegram seems to be supporting them.

I did some googling around and it seems to be a well known problem that in-app use of WebRTC is not supported and that Google Sign In will throw a `disallowed_useragent` (I tried stackoverflow.com via LinkedIn chat and the same problem occurred).

My question is - if you had a similar issue, what workarounds did you implement to avoid users being blocked from using your website? Is there any way to escape the in-app browser straight to native Safari? It would be nice to at least show a button that would open the website straight in Safari instead of in-app.

[EDIT]: For now my current workaround is to recognise in-app (with an NPM module called detect-inapp) and show a different screen to users with a link to copy. It's terrible but the only thing that seems to work for now.

Comment: Hi, any updates on this?

Comment: Nothing unfortunately, still stuck with showing the message